# Custom FBA login page. Modify Default.aspx

Tags: forms-authentication, ntlm, custom-login-page

I want to have a custom login FBA page. I want the FBA page to be the default page. This is not the problem.

I'm wondering how to modify my default.aspx page (the one which show form authentication), to add an "html link" like "Admin login", that permit us to log with NTLM Authentication.

I have to precise that I'm not a developer at all. But I can understand a little bit html/js/etc.

If someone has a great idea, because I think it's just a few lines to add.

Thanks in advance,

Nico.

P.S : I've read [this](http://sharepointdevblog.wordpress.com/2013/05/15/create-custom-login-page-mixed-authentication-sharepoint-2013), but code is too complicated for me, I don't know what modification I have to do in order to do what I want.

P.S2 : I can't find physically the /_windows/default.aspx page ...
Because I tried to add this in my /_forms/default.aspx

```
<a href="/_windows/default.aspx"><h2>Test<h2></a>
```

But when I click on my link, it brings me to the dropdownlist page ...

I've also tried this :
    [Test](/_layouts/_windows/default.aspx)
But now it brings me to an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use the link:

```
<a href="/_windows/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F&Source=%2F">Windows Login</a>
```

You need the 'ReturnUrl' and 'Source' parameters in the link for it to work.

This will always redirect the user to the root of the site after login though. You'll need to add some backend logic (or potentially js) if you want to adjust to return them to the exact page they were attempting to access ('Source' parameter).